# Como remover lixos nas telas de impressão

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Como crio um CSS para remover os lixos como na imagem em anexo.

Estou usando bootstrap.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com CSS puro basta criar em sua folha de estilos um `@media print { }` ou você também pode ter um arquivo a parte e para isso basta adicionar um link stylesheet no `head`, como o trecho de código abaixo mostra.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/print.css" media="print" />
```

Exemplos:

```
@media print {
    * {
        background:transparent !important;
        color:#000 !important;
        text-shadow:none !important;
        filter:none !important;
        -ms-filter:none !important;
    }

    body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        line-height: 1.4em;
    }

    header {
        display: none;
    } 

    footer {
        display: none;
    }

    .content {
        display: block;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**Explicação:**

Como a tela de impressão costuma ser modificada/adaptada para ser melhor visualizada no papel, talvez você queira modificar sua página inteira, então resolvi mostrar alguns exemplos para você.

- Com o `*` você está aplicando os atributos para a página toda e como
  alguns estilos já vem carregados por padrão, eu resolvi resetalos
  para ter uma tela de impressão limpa.
- A mesma coisa acontece com o `body`, apenas reseto alguns atributos e
  aplico uma altura para as linhas.
- Agora no `Header, Footer e .content` eu apenas apliquei o display,
  que você usará para controlar o que vai aparecer e o que vai sumir.
  Caso seja necessário que um elemento apareça somente na tela de
  impressão, você teria que aplicar um `display: block;` nele dentro da
  `@media print` e um `display: none;` fora, para que ela apareça
  somente quando for impressa.
- Também é importante lembrar das imagens, pois dependendo do seu
  estilo elas podem ficar para fora da área de impressão, então mostrei
  o `max-width: 100%;` que não deixa a imagem passar da largura da
  página.

Answer (score 5):

Utilize as seguintes classes do bootstrap

- `hidden-print`: para não mostrar na impressão - será exibido no HTML
- `visible-print`: para mostrar na impressão - não será exibido no HTML

Exemplo:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="hidden-print">
  <p>Não mostra na impressão mas mostra no HTML</p>
  <a href="javascript:window.print()">Imprmir</a> 
</div>
<div class="visible-print">
  <p>Mostra na impressão mas não mostra no HTML</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Mostra em ambos</p>
</div>
```

Você ainda tem a opção de criar estilos que serão usados apenas na impressão, consigo lembrar de duas maneiras

1 - Criando uma folha de estilos somente para a impressão e importando no seu HTML com a tag `media="print"`

```
<link href="style.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" />`
```

2 - Ou usando a meta tag `@media print { }` em sua folha de estilos

```
@media print {
    /* Your styles here */
}
```

Comment: Ultilizei o hidden-print mais ai a página toda fica em branco,sem os textos;dentro daquelas tabelas,tenho textos que precisam ser exibidos.

Comment: A classe `hidden-print` irá ocultar todos os elementos filhos do componente que você atribuiu a classe.

Comment: Ok,Obrigado,utilizei o @media print {.